# Issues after migration of Asp.Net Core RC1 to RC2

Tags: asp.net-core

We have migrated our project from Asp.Net core RC1 to RC2. We are getting 2 compilation errors in the following places after the migrations.

First Issue is in the `startup.cs`:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

...

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
       
       
       ...
}
```

Error Details:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'  Firebolt.SecurityService..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0   C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Security\src\Firebolt.Security\Startup.cs  58  Active

Second Issue:

```
[Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    [Migration("00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema")]
    partial class CreateIdentitySchema
    {
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
     ...
}
```

Error Details:

> Error CS0115  'CreateIdentitySchema.BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override Firebolt.SecurityService..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0   C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Security\src\Firebolt.Security\Migrations\00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.Designer.cs  15  Active

What is the fix for these 2 issues?

Comment: I was getting a similar error for my AddMvc() line in my startup.cs which was due to having an incompatible version of swashbuckle in my project.json. Had to update it from `6.0.0-rc1-final` to `6.0.0-beta901`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solutions for both of the issues. I am posting it here which might be useful to others

First Issue

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
> properties:
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser,
> TRole>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'
> and
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentity<TUser,
> TRole>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'  Firebolt.SecurityService..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

the Issue was with the following 2 config entries in Project.json. I replaced the existing entries with the following 2 and it solved the issues

```
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
 "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
```

> Error CS0115  'CreateIdentitySchema.BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder)': no
> suitable method found to
> override  Firebolt.SecurityService..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Find/Replace the existing using namespaces in all the migrations related classes

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity with using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Answer (score 23):

I also ran into this error in my migrations using dot net core 2.0. Hopefully this can help someone.

> Error CS0115  'init.BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override

It was after a refactoring where my migration classes had been moved a new namespace. I had moved them from `MyApp.Migrations` to `MyApp.Web.Migrations` and dot net did not like that.

I moved them back to `MyApp.Migrations` and they stopped complaining.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but pointed me to the problem. After the move the .Designer file didn't pick up the namespace change. Updating that fixed it

Comment: The problem you had and I had fixed is that both partial files have to be in the same namespace.

Answer (score 4):

I had Error

> CS0115  'CreateIdentitySchema.BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder)':
> no suitable method found to override
> Firebolt.SecurityService..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

The error pointed to a designer [image]
As founded I am accidently change the name of migration file (the first file on the picture above)
[image]

finally I have returned `A` back and everything continue working.

Comment: In my case the problem was the wrong namespace, because I moved all the migrations and entities in a separate library.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same solution as @span Migrations were moved from the *`.Web.`* project to the *`.Database.`* project. But my migration still was in `Web`. It causes with error. Following @span solution, I just changed the namespace of the migration and it works!